# Is it true that HTML forms cannot submit (with enter) if theres no submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I find that if I have a form with no submit button, it will not submit (with enter key). But if I add a submit button, it works

No submit button http://jsfiddle.net/VxF42/1/
With submit button http://jsfiddle.net/VxF42/

I am alittle confused as to why this works -> 1 form element / no submit button

http://jsfiddle.net/VxF42/1/

It seems like if I have a form with more than 1 form element, I need a submit button? How can I have no submit button. I will be using jQuery UI Dialog's Buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it true that HTML forms cannot
>   submit (with enter) if theres no
>   submit button?

Depends on how you code. By default this won't happen.

But you can use javascript to triger the submit event of a form by handling keyboard event and checking for enter key.

Comment: I think he means not only pure HTML as the question has 'javascript', 'jquery', and 'jquery-ui' tag :D

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not true.

It seems that as long as an input element (or any other applicable form-related element, I think) that is the child of a form element has focus, hitting the enter key submits the form.

```
<form>
 <input>
</form>
```

Tested that in Firefox 4, IE 8, Chrome 9, Opera 10, and Safari 5.

Comment: With Firefox 4 this is not the case if there are multiple input elements, even if all are simply text fields.

Answer (score 1):

in jquery, you can use the .submit() method on an input element I believe.  I know I've done this same thing without a submit button.